# Pointer to block pointer

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, kiwi, promisekit

I have a method using promises (PMKPromise), that I'd like to unit test using the library Kiwi.

My method looks like this:

```
- (void)fetchData {
[PMKPromise new:^(PMKPromiseFulfiller fulfill, PMKPromiseRejecter reject) {
    // make the request
}].then(^(NSDictionary *data){
    // code that I'd like to test
});
}
```

I want to capture and execute the promise completion block (called "then"), and I managed to do it this way (with a mocked promise):

```
// capture the promise completion block
__block void (^capturedBlock)(NSDictionary *);

[thePromise stub:@selector(then) withBlock:^id(NSArray *params) {
    return ^(id block){
        capturedBlock = block;
        return nil;
    };
}];

[myObj fetchData];

// execute the block
capturedBlock(@{});
```

What I'd like to do now is to hide this ugly code in a category that I could easily use in the future when unit testing promises.

I'd like to pass a block "double pointer" as a method argument.

This could be the implementation:

```
@interface NSObject (PMKPromiseTest)

- (void)captureThenBlock:(void (^ *)(NSDictionary *))capturedBlock;

@end

@implementation NSObject (PMKPromiseTest)

- (void)captureThenBlock:(void (^ *)(NSDictionary *))capturedBlock {

    [self stub:@selector(then) withBlock:^id(NSArray *params) {
        return ^(id block){
            *capturedBlock = block;
            return nil;
        };
    }];
}

@end
```

And this is how I would use it:

```
// capture the promise completion block:
void (^capturedBlock)(NSDictionary *);
[thePromise captureThenBlock:&capturedBlock];

[myObj fetchData];

// execute it
capturedBlock(@{});  // Exception! captureBlock is nil
```

Unfortunately this code does not work. When stepping in, the block is indeed captured. But once out, at the moment of executing the captured block, it is nil.

Comment: You said it's asynchronous, so it won't have been set when you think it will...

Comment: You've left out too much code context to be able to see what it going on.

Comment: This looks like an XY question. Instead of asking why your attempt at solving a problem doesn't work (the Y problem), you should tell us what is the actual problem you are trying to solve (the X problem).

Comment: you haven't showed what happens in the "..."

Comment: What happens in the "..." is the execution of the code that is unit-tested, ie the code that is creating the promise.